# Getting android.intent.action.TIME_SET twice when manually change time

Tags: android, time, action

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which watches `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` and `android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED`.

```
<receiver android:name="SystemBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

/** not true, see below
Whenever one of these actions happens, the receiver will open an activity.
All work well except when I change the minute part of the clock, the `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` will activate twice, which leads to the activity opening twice.
I find it is strange because if I change the hour part of the clock, `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` will activate only once.
*/
My test phone is Galaxy Nexus with 4.2.1. Is this a system bug in 4.2.1 or have I done something wrong?

-----------edit by myself------------
Here is some logs that may helps.
Whenever I change the minute, the hour or the date, my activity will launch twice.

```
02-01 21:16:11.781: D/SystemClock(9012): Setting time of day to sec=1359724560
02-01 21:16:00.023: V/AlarmClock(8932): AlarmInitReceiver finished
02-01 21:16:00.031: D/SystemClock(9012): Setting time of day to sec=1359724560
```

I do't know why I just change the time in the system settings part once, but the system call the setting time twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verified this behavior on my own Nexus.

However, you should not start an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver. I recommend that you use [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)!

This way it does not matter if you get the Broadcast twice, because the notification will only update, but not duplicate.

Comment: it will not duplicate but if the notification has sound it will play twice.